# GNURadio OOT Module - Undefined symbol error

Tags: python, c++, gnuradio, undefined-symbol

I am implementing a convolutional encoder-decoder OOT Module in GNU Radio 3.8 in **C++**.

When running the python tests I've written for the encoder and decoder, I get the following error:

`ImportError: undefined symbol: _ZN2gr5a3sat13conv_dec_impl9generatorE`

The `generator` variable is declared in the `conv_dec_impl` **header** file as:

`inline static const bool generator[2][7] = {{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}}`

Also, in the tests' **python** file, when importing a3sat_swig, I get this error: `No module named 'a3sat_swig'`

Could it be related to the CMakeLists file?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In case you are working on an open source project share a link to it.

Comment: Please search for the error message. It's easy to find out what causes "undefined symbol" and subsequest Python `ImportError` exception. Concerning your actual question, please extract a [mcve], which will give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The generator variable is declared in the conv_dec_impl header file as:
>
> inline static const bool generator[2][7] = {{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}}

Move the `generator` definition to the `.cpp` file. Also make sure you don't have a previous version of your OOT block that lacks this symbol already installed.

> Also, in the tests' python file, when importing a3sat_swig, I get this error: No module named 'a3sat_swig'

Open `python/__init__.py` and either change `ImportError` to `ModuleNotFoundError` or remove the `try` and `except`. See [issue 4761](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/4761)

> Could it be related to the CMakeLists file?

No, most probably is not related to CMakeLists file.

Comment: I actually just tried moving the ```generator``` definition to the ```.cpp``` file and it worked.  

Also changed this in the ```python/__init__.py```.

Thanks for your help!